# wpf datagrid add new item at bottom with manual sort

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I do the following in code behind : when user clicks onto last datagrid item which has a special template, I add a new item to the collection view, then sort by descending order so that newly added blank line sits at bottom. Then I programmatically switch this new item to edit mode.

However, at this point, items don't get visually sorted *when I click a first time onto header after finishing new line edition, it seems. Header icon changes though*. New line was displayed at right place for edition.

Thank you for guiding me.

```
            DataGridRow row = sender_ as DataGridRow;

            if (row.Item != CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder || row.Template != _adressesDataGridNewRowControlTemplate) return;

            // In case we click on dedicated bottom line with special template
            // (it's tuned new item placeholder, we've setup datagrid with CanUserAddRows        
            // to false

            // 1. Globally commit datagrid (there are validations errors but we're willing to keep them)
            AddressGrid.CommitEdit();
            AddressGrid.UpdateLayout();

            // 2. Add a new item to collection view
            ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AddressGrid.ItemsSource);
            view.AddNewItem(new Adresse());
            view.CommitNew();
            view.Refresh();

            // 3. Programmatically descending sorting... new item will be at bottom
            // right below new item placeholder

            foreach (DataGridColumn dataColumn in AddressGrid.Columns)
                dataColumn.SortDirection = null;

            DataGridColumn selectedDataColumn = AddressGrid.Columns[1];
            selectedDataColumn.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;
            view.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(selectedDataColumn.Header as string, ListSortDirection.Descending));
            view.Refresh();

            // 4. Get this added line reference
            int iAddedLineIndex = AddressGrid.Items.Count - 2;
            row = ObjectTreeHelper.GetRow(AddressGrid, iAddedLineIndex);
            // apply edit template
            row.Template = _adressesDataGridDefaultRowControlTemplate;
            AddressGrid.UpdateLayout();

            // 5. Go to edition mode
            AddressGrid.CurrentItem = row.Item;

            // Set focus to desired cell (2nd here)
            DataGridCell cell = ObjectTreeHelper.GetCell(AddressGrid, iAddedLineIndex, 1);
            cell.Focus();
            AddressGrid.BeginEdit();

            // 6. Consider left mouse click event as handled
            e_.Handled = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my code was OK in its main structure.

I tested again with default datagrid and line addition/sorting behavior. It appears that added line goes sorted when new line ends edit, this is the only difference.

I had a look about adding automatic sorting after new line ends editing but didn't succeed. I'm ok with newly added validated line to stay at bottom so will answer my own question as I'm satisfied.